# Saving Date in MySQL? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Im am learning / Training  MySQL , PHP I`m **beginner** at PHP
So i was trying to make a CRUD, so i was trying to save Date in database . so i used input type "DATE" in form. but id didn't worked quite well it just doesn't insert date just saves it as 0000-00-00 (MySQL datatype DATE)
In form:

```
    <input type="date" name="release">
```

And here.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
 $ename= $_GET['name'];
 $edate= $_GET['release'];
 $eseas= $_GET['season'];

 $insert= "INSERT into episodes (name, date, season) values($ename,$edate,$eseas) ";
```

I am just learning PHP, if there is a better way to do that please recommend me
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: your values are strings, so they needs to be quoted - `values('$ename','$edate','$eseas')`. note you are open to sql injection. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug #1: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Go to this link and read and UNDERSTAND the problem before you go any farther

Bug #2: You haven't quoted your values, so your PHP

```
$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES(...,$edate,...)"
```

is going to produce this SQL:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (...,2015-08-20,...)
```

Since you have no quotes around your date value, it's not really a date. It's a mathematical subtraction, and you're really doing `2015-8-20 => 1987`, and the query is extecuted as

```
INSERT ... VALUES (...,1987,...)
```

Since 1987 isn't a valid date string (mysql expects yyyy-mm-dd), you get the all-zeroes date in your db.

Ignoring the injection problem, you need:

```
$insert= "INSERT into episodes (name, date, season) values($ename,'$edate',$eseas) ";
                                                                  ^------^
```

And similarly for any other field value that isn't a plain number. If you don't quote strings, the strings are interpreted as field/table names, which probably don't exist.

Comment: Thank You , Marc, Seems Like i fixed the problem So stupid of me :-/
As for SQl injection, As i mentioned im actually Basic MYSQL queries. so i dont think that actually matters alot right now. but i will look into MySQL vulnerabilities and stuff once i have basic mysql and php knowledge.
Thanks again :)